# React vs SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, signalr

I build web apps using ASP MVC and I am looking at using ReactJS. I have seen a few examples of React integrated into an ASP.NET MVC project and I don't really see the value over SignalR, which is what I use now for all real-time updates and communications.

I am hoping someone can go over the benefits of using React vs SignalR or even why I should be using React. Its popularity makes me think there is more to it that I'm just not seeing and I would hate to fall behind if it is more powerful and can help me do more.

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: SignalR is wonderful, but, many doesn't seems to understand how it works... Also I think that this are very different technologies, maybe they can complement each other but are not the same

Comment: As you mention, SignalR is about real time updates, React is about organizing templates. They are technologies that would complement each other, not replace one another. What React replaces is your views (Razor / asp pages etc)

Comment: I've been riding a bike all my life, but recently a friend recommended I should use two screens with my PC. I don't think that having two screens is better than riding a bike.
Update: I stopped eating butter.

Answer (score 3):

React is used to build a single page apps or SPA, this will give you a desktop like UI, if you want it to be more interactive, then you can use it with SignalR to receive real time updates from the back end.

Facebook site alone is the idea of React, ex: responsive, no page refresh.
Integrating it with something like SignalR, adds the real time notifications about comments and posts

Answer (score 1):

You should'nt compare apples and oranges.
React is a JS Library for building User Interfaces and SignalR is an abstraction, which will help you to send messages from server to client (also the other side).